# SonarQube - Coverity c# plugin issue

Tags: c#, plugins, sonarqube, coverity

I'm having a problem after adding Coverity plugin into SonarQube. I get this plugin (the only Coverity plugin I found) from [this](https://github.com/coverity/coverity-sonar-plugin). When testing the plugin, I ran into this one:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Multiple entries with same key: cs=C# and cs=C#
```

The only way Sonar continues to run (by many times I have researched) is to delete this plugin or the C# plugin. Our projects require Quality Profiles from both of these, so is there any way these two stay together without causing any issues (like Java Profiles)? My thanks in advance.

P/s: This happens to all SonarQube versions from 5.1 to 5.6 (which I tested) and all C# plugins regardless of version.